# Python Spacy beginner : similarities function

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

In the tutorial example of spaCy in Python the results of `apples.similarity(oranges)` is
`0.39289959293092641`
instead of  `0.7857989796519943`

Any reasons for that?
Original docs of the tutorial 
https://spacy.io/docs/
A tutorial with a different answer to the one I get: 
http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-spacy

Thanks

Comment: Can you at least link to this example?

Answer (score 9):

That appears to be a bug in spacy.

Somehow `vector_norm` is incorrectly calculated.

```
import spacy
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load("en")
# using u"apples" just as an example
apples = nlp.vocab[u"apples"]
print apples.vector_norm
# prints 1.4142135381698608, or sqrt(2)
print np.sqrt(np.dot(apples.vector, apples.vector))
# prints 1.0
```

Then `vector_norm` is used in `similarity`, which always returns a value that is always half of the correct value.

```
def similarity(self, other):
    if self.vector_norm == 0 or other.vector_norm == 0:
        return 0.0
    return numpy.dot(self.vector, other.vector) / (self.vector_norm * other.vector_norm)
```

If you are ranking similarity scores for synonyms, this might be OK. But if you need the correct cosine similarity score, then the result is incorrect.

I submitted the issue [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/522). Hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ethan's report on the issue tracker, this is now fixed.

You'll also get the GloVe vectors by default now — so similarities should in general be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

That can be because one of the comparing text has an out-of-vocabulary word. Note: OOV words are different for different spacy models! Models have different vocabularies.